# Subquery in yii2

Tags: yii2, subquery

I have 2 tables

1. projects (id,name)
2. accounts (id,project_id,account_name)

I want to find all projects with their account_name  like this

```
SELECT Project.*,(SELECT account_name FROM accounts WHERE projectid = Project.id) FROM projects as Project
```

Please let me know how this possible in yii2. 
I can easily done it in cakephp where we can use virtualFields.is there any functionality in yii2 like cakephp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should be able to just write this into the `select()` call as an additional column (column names with parentheses are treated as DB expressions automatically)

```
Project::find()
    ->select([
        'Project.*', 
        '(SELECT account_name FROM accounts WHERE projectid = Project.id) AS account_name'
    ])
    ->asArray()->all();
```

If you like to have the column present in the ActiveRecord class instead of an array, declare an additional public property which receives the field:

```
class Project extends ActiveRecord {
    // ...
    public $account_name;
    // ...
}
```

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#select()-detail

Comment: hi i want only a single records . what use instead of ->all();

Comment: Fixed with one() mehod

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more readable.
Also there is no raw query.

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'p.*',
        'a.account_name'
    ])
    ->from('projects p')
    ->innerJoin('accounts a', 'a.id = p.account_id')
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
                    ->select(['*','(SELECT account_name FROM accounts WHERE id = projects.account_id) as account_name'])
                    ->from('projects')
                    ->where(['id' => $id])
                    ->all();
```

This is working for me.